# In a Git diff, can I exclude diffs that contain certain strings?

Tags: git, git-diff

With Git diff, is there a way to exclude lines that contain a given string? (A parallel, of sorts, is to exclude diffs containing only white spaces with `-w`.) Sometimes a Git diff returns long lists of changes that are not meaningful at a given stage of development.

For example, patches that change only [UUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), or those that change only 'weight'. At times these changes are not significant, but nonetheless result in diffs containing many, many lines.

The Git documentation seem to mention features close to exclusion by string (`git grep` and `git log -L`). Is there something out there that I've not yet found, or that I've just not yet used correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer from the doc page on [Git-diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt--Iltregexgt)

```
-I<regex>
--ignore-matching-lines=<regex>

    Ignore changes whose all lines match <regex>. This option may be specified more than once.
```

### Example putting it to use

`git diff -I"^uuid: " -- config/sync` will return a succinct list that ignores the changes in any line starting with 'uuid: '.

Comment: I forgot I'd asked this question back in 2019. A few years ago I found the answer. I'll add it here as a reminder to my future (forgetful) self, and in hopes it's useful to others.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to set a diff textconv filter to adjust the diff output.  If you edit the .git/info/attributes file (creating it if it doesn't exist), you can enter a line that says *.c diff=uuid, which will make all C files use the "uuid" diff filter.  You could also write this in .gitattributes, or in any other valid gitattributes file (see the man page for details).

Once you've done that, you can specify a diff filter in your .git/config file, or in your personal .gitconfig file. that specifies how to modify the file to render diffs.  For example, you could write something like this:

```
[diff "uuid"]
    textconv = "perl -pe 's/[0-9a-f]{8}(-[0-9a-f]{4}){3}-[0-9a-f]{12}/UUID-PLACEHOLDER/'"
```

That will have perl modify all your diffs to convert your UUIDs to `UUID-PLACEHOLDER`. You can perform arbitrary transformations on your files to modify them as you please for diff output.  You can see more about this by running `man gitattributes`.

Comment: That saved me with Magento 1 upgrade when it comes to copyright and license tags. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Not the I know of.

You can exclude diff files by their status ([`--diff-filter=\[(A|C|D|M|R|T|U|X|B)…​\[*\]\]`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---diff-filterACDMRTUXB82308203)), but not by their content.

You would need to wrap the git diff and post-processs its result in order to filter by content.